# Which classifier can classify according to non axis parallel decision boundaries?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have some 2d data which looks like it could be well classified by an area described by two intersecting straight lines. These lines won't necessarily by at right angles to each other.  Here is a simple example where the two lines would be more or less at right angles:

[image]

Is there a suitable classifier for this? Logistic regression will give me one straight line but I am not sure what will give me two as a decision boundary.  A decision tree will give me two that are axis parallel which isn't really want I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give [Support Vector Machine (SVM)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#classification) a try. There are [multiple kernels](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#classification) that can be used with SVM, like

- Linear
- Polynomial
- RBF (Radial Basis Function)
- Sigmoid

You can even specify custom kernels as mentioned [in this list](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#custom-kernels).

Here is an image of decision boundaries over Iris dataset, taken [from this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html)
[image]

**References**

- [Difference between various SVM kernels](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90736/the-difference-of-kernels-in-svm)
- [Selecting Kernels for SVM](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/06/select-support-vector-machine-kernels.html)
- [Custom kernel SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_custom_kernel.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-custom-kernel-py)